# Issue with EventDataBatch.TryAdd() in Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer namespace

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

What will happen if the size of the event data object is more than 4MB while creating the EventDataBatch using  EventDataBatch.TryAdd() in Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer namespace?

As per the MS document it will return true or false.There are two types of exception
ArgumentNullException - Thrown when the EventData is null and ObjectDisposedException -
Thrown when the batch is already disposed.

What exception will it throw in case of the event data object is more than 4MB?

Comment: The batch is limited to the maximum size allowed by the specific Event Hub that the producer is connected to, as defined in https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas.  At present, the maximum size for any SKU is 1 MB.   I'm not sure where the 4 MB number that you're discussing comes from - but it's well over the limit for a single operation.   That said, Peter's answer to your actual question is correct.

Answer (score 2):

None, it will return false and the event data will not have been added. By having a boolean return value there is no need to throw an exception when the size is too big. That is the whole idea of this method, to add event data and in that process check the total size in a safe way.